# Incorrect output using strcmp

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I'm doing the day 8 of the 30 days of code in HackerRank and I am having a problem with `strcmp`.
The code asks the user for names of people and their numbers, then asks for other names, if a name wasn't entered before, then it outputs `Not found`, but if it was then it outputs the name and his number. But for some reason, the output only works in the last loop of the `for` statement.
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[100];
    int number;
} phonebook;

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    do {
        scanf("%i", &n);
    } while (n < 1 || n > 100000);
    
    int i = 0;
    phonebook people[n];
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%s %i", people[i].name, &people[i].number);
    }
    
    char othernames[n][100];
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%s", othernames[i]);
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (strcmp(othernames[i], people[i].name) == 0) {
            printf("%s=%i\n", people[i].name, people[i].number);
        } else {
            printf("Not found\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcmp(othernames[i], people[i].name)` shouldn't there be a second loop so that every `othernames` is compared with every `people[].name`?

Comment: `char othernames[100][n];` should be `char othernames[n][100];`

Comment: `%s` scans for a *single* space-delimited word. Are you sure the names are just one word each?

Comment: Or why store the whole list of `othernames` at all?  You don't need any given one except to compare it to the phonebook, so it would be more memory-efficient and no more complex to compare each one to the phonebook immediately after reading it, then to reuse the same space for the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't find the `othernames` from the beginning to end to compare `people`every time, so you need to replace

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (strcmp(othernames[i], people[i].name) == 0) {
    printf("%s=%i\n", people[i].name, people[i].number);
  } 
  else {
    printf("Not found\n");
  }
}
```

to

```
bool found = false;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for ( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++ ) {
    if (strcmp(othernames[j], people[i].name) == 0) {
      printf("%s=%i\n", people[i].name, people[i].number);
      found = true;
    } 
  }
}

if ( found == false ) printf("Not found\n");
```

Comment: Thanks, I just implemented it in a different way, I put the bool inside of the loop because if it's outside when it changes to true it will always be true right? It worked, but now the problem is that the code is still taking too long to execute. I think it's because of the `strcmp` that is called a lot of times in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `othernames` should just be an array of `char`, not a matrix. And for each othername entered, you must scan whole phonebook to find it or display `Not found`. As coded, you only test if the i-th othername typed happens to correspond to the i-th entry in the phone book.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[100];
    int number;
} phonebook;

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    do {
        if (scanf("%i", &n) != 1)
            return 1;
    } while (n < 1 || n > 100000);
    
    phonebook people[n];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%99s %i", people[i].name, &people[i].number) != 2)
            return 1;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char othername[100];
    
        if (scanf("%99s", othername) != 1)
            break;
    
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (strcmp(othername, people[j].name) == 0) {
                printf("%s=%i\n", people[i].name, people[i].number);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == n) {
            printf("Not found\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that it is probably not a good idea to store phone numbers as `int` values. Better use a `char` array so an initial `0` is significant and to store longer numbers.